# $\left| x \right| \le 3\left[ {\sqrt x } \right]$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $\left| x \right| \le 3\lfloor {\sqrt x } \rfloor$.
What is the answer to this inequality?

Comment: Did you peraps mean to write the [floor function $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). This is done with the commands `\lfloor` and `\rfloor`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what's the point of the absolute value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly any possible answers must be non-negative due to the $\sqrt{x}$ term.

Secondly, let's find an upper limit. Consider the equation: $x\leq3\sqrt{x}$. This leads to $x^2\leq9x$ and hence $x\leq9$. So any possible solutions to the question must be in $[0,9]$.

Due to the floor function you need to consider several different cases.

- Case A: $x=0$

This is a valid solution.

- Case B: $0<x<1$

In this case the right hand side becomes zero so there are no solutions in this range.

- Case C: $1\leq x<4$

In this case the right hand side becomes $3$ so the equation becomes: $x\leq3$ so an additional part of the solution is $1\leq x\leq 3$.

- Case D: $4\leq x< 9$

In this case the right hand side becomes $6$ so the equation becomes: $x\leq6$ so an additional part of the solution is $4\leq x\leq6$.

- Case E: $x=9$

This is a valid solution.

---

So putting it all together gives:

$$x\in\{0\}\ \cup\ [1,3] \cup\ [4,6]\ \cup\ \{9\}$$

or alternatively:

$$x=0\ \lor\ 1\leq x\leq3\ \lor\ 4\leq x\leq6\ \lor\ x=9$$

Comment: (+1) Good logic, but I would write the solution either as $$x\in\{0\}\cup[1,3]\cup[4,6]\cup\{9\}$$ or as $$x=0\lor 1\le x\le3\lor4\le x\le6\lor x=9$$

Comment: What the mathjax for the V version of OR?

Comment: Right click on the MathJax and choose "Show Math As > TeX Commands"  to see that $\lor$ is `\lor`

Comment: Thanks, had forgotten about right click.

Answer (score 2):

As $\sqrt x$ is not defined for $x<0$, $|x|=x$.

First of all,
$$\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor<\sqrt x+ 1$$ gives 
$$x< 3\sqrt x+3\iff (\sqrt x-\frac32)^2<\frac {21}4$$

, which is clearly wrong for $x\le 16$.

Thus, we only have $4$ cases to analyze:

- $\lfloor \sqrt x\rfloor=0$, i.e. $0\le x<1$:

This gives $x\le 0\implies x=0$.

- $\lfloor \sqrt x\rfloor=1$, i.e. $1\le x<4$:

This gives $x\le 3$.

So, $1\le x\le 3$.

- $\lfloor \sqrt x\rfloor=2$, i.e. $4\le x<9$:

This gives $x\le 6$.

So, $4\le x\le 6$.

- $\lfloor \sqrt x\rfloor=3$, i.e. $9\le x<16$:

This gives $x\le 9$.

So, $x=9$.